# $.ajax() not accepting php array

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm using ajax to return results from a table (mysql). Ajax calls are made using jquery.
Databases are accessed using PDOs.

PHP

```
    function fetchQuestions() {
            $database = "answerMe";  // the name of the database.
            $server = "127.0.0.1";  // server to connect to.
            $db_user = "name";  // mysql username to access the database with.
            $db_pass = "password";  // mysql password to access the database with.
            $table = "questions";
            $result = "";

            try {
              $testh = new PDO ("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $db_user, $db_pass);
              $testh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
              $testh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
              $sql = "select COUNT(*) from questions";
              $pstatement = $testh->prepare($sql);
              $success = $pstatement->execute();
              $num = $pstatement->fetchColumn();
              $sql = "select * from $table";
              $pstatement = $testh->prepare($sql);
              $success = $pstatement->execute();
              print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
              $result = $pstatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
              return $result;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
              echo "Following error was encountered <br />";
              echo $e->getMessage();
            }
    }
    $function = $_POST['function'];    
    $response = array();
    $data = "";

    switch($function) {
             .
             .
             .      

             case('recData'):
                //$qs = array('w','k');
                $qs = fetchQuestions();
                $response['records'] = $qs;
                    break;
    }    
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Jquery(ajax part)

```
    function AjaxReq(){
            this.sendSuccess = false;
            this.recSuccess = false;
            this.send = sendData;
            this.rec = recData;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    function recData() {
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "ajax.php",
               data: {  'function': 'recData',
                                    },
               dataType: "json",

               success: function(data){
                       alert('rec succeeded');
                       this.recSuccess = true;
                       for(var i = 0; i < data.records.length; ++i) {
                                    $("#details").append(data.records[i]);
                            }
               },
            });
    }
```

Jquery (calling ajax)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var reqTest = new AjaxReq();
            $("#done").bind('click',function(){
                    reqTest.rec();
            });
    });
```

In the PHP code, case 'recData', if I uncomment //$qs = array('w','k');, I get the results.

This made me conclude maybe $qs wasn't an array probably. But using is_array(), its was proven otherwise.

I have tried my best to keep irrelevant code away from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print statement in the following lines created the problem.

```
    $success = $pstatement->execute();
    print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
    $result = $pstatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
```

The meddled with the JSON's encoding and created all the trouble. Removing it solves the problem.

Ajax call must always accompany error handlers to help debugging.

```
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred! ' + ( errorThrown ? errorThrown :
            xhr.status ));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this java script var_dump library to debag Your data response.
https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/var/var_dump.js

Answer (score 0):

I have trimmed your code as outlined in [**sscce**](http://sscce.org/). You should avoid using Try/Catch blocks unless you are going to handle the catched exception eg if database down.

```
$database = "answerMe";  // the name of the database.
$server = "127.0.0.1";  // server to connect to.
$db_user = "name";  // mysql username to access the database with.
$db_pass = "password";  // mysql password to access the database with.
$testh = new PDO ("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $db_user, $db_pass);
$testh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$testh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "select * from $table";
$pstatement = $testh->prepare($sql);
$success = $pstatement->execute();
$result = $pstatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
var_dump($result);
```

[**var_dump($result)**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) dumps information about a variable.
If the result is that required you can incrementally add features testing as you go.

**EDIT**
Assuming result is satisfactory.

1. Change `var_dump($result)` to `echo json_encode($result)`
2. Add `header('Content-Type: application/json')` after `<?php`
3. Save code at ajaxtest.php
4. Use the following code to show JSON (Using [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/))
5. If results satisfactory incorporate into your own code

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('ajaxtest.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $('#result').append('<p>' + data[i].records + '</p>');
        });
    });   
});
```

**EDIT 2**
Rather than use `$sql = "select * from $table"`  you should use `` $sql = "select `records` from $table" ``. This would eliminate needing to use [**fetchColumn()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.ph). `fetchColumn(1)` retrieves column 2 NOT column 1

Comment: var_dump isn't helping me understand why my ajax call is failing

Comment: I started afresh. Created tmp.js, tmp.html and tmp.php. Made the respective chnages. Code now looks like this.

`code`

Comment: Did that! Now I see eleven 'undefined's. Now what I also realised is there are 11 rows in my table. I added another row to the table and html output also showed another 'undefined'.

Furthermore, i tried echoing the rows from php script again like last time by commenting out the header() and json_encode(). Rows get displayed without any issues.

Comment: Remember when working with Ajax/PHP/MySQL to keep it simple until you can send and receive data. Once this is achieved you can add features as required. Do you require any more help??

Comment: Thank you. But yes. Its showed 'undefined' instead of the column value. Why is that?

Comment: @ManasJayanth In your code the line `$("#details").append(data.records[i]);` indicates only 1 field is returned with the name `records`. If this is not the correct name it will show as undefined. I have a feeling you may be returning more than one field if this is the case you will need to to try `append(data.field1[i]+data.field2[i])`etc

Comment: It infact is just one field. If you notice,I have used fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1), which fetches values from just one column. When I don't use ajax, I am able see them